# SwiftUI App with Core Location and Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, core-location

I am working on an app that tracks the user's location and saves some data related to the location in CoreData. I am new to SwiftUI, so my question is related to where/how is the best place in the app to save the location data into CoreData.

Currently, I have a setup that is very similar to the accepted solution here:
[How to get Current Location using SwiftUI, without ViewControllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57681885/how-to-get-current-location-using-swiftui-without-viewcontrollers)

Therefore I won't repeat the code that is already in the above link but will make references to it. So you may want to take a look at the answer before reading the rest of my problem statement.

So in class LocationManager I have:

```
@Published var userLocations: [CLLocation]? {
    willSet {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    guard let location = locations.last else { return }
    let howOldIsTheLastLocationData = abs(location.timestamp.timeIntervalSinceNow)
    if howOldIsTheLastLocationData < 15 && location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 && location.horizontalAccuracy < 15 {
        if userLocations == nil {
            userLocations = []
        }
        userLocations?.append(location)
    }
    print(#function, location, location.latitudeString, location.longitudeString, location.altitude, howOldIsTheLastLocationData)
}
```

Therefore userLocations is what I would like to observe in my View and also save into my CoreData.

Now in my View I have:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
@State var segment: Segment?
@ObservedObject var locationManager = LocationManager()

var userPath: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]? {
    if let userLocations = locationManager.userLocations {            
        return userLocations.map( { $0.coordinate })
    }
    return nil
}

var body: some View {
    // A MapView Uses userPath to show the path on a MKMapView        
    MapView(pathCoordinates: userPath ?? [])
    
    // There is a button that by pressing it, it creates a Segment which is an Entity in my CoreData with time data.
}
```

So far everything that I mentioned above is working. I am getting the location updates, showing the path on a MapView. I am able to create Segments (and save into CoreData) by pressing the Start button. Now the piece I am looking for is for every location update that goes into userLocations, I would like to create a new instance of another CoreData Entity that is called PointOnPath that is associated with a Segment. So Segment has a one-to-many relationship to PointOnPath. What I don't know is where I should call something like the following lines of code:

```
  let point = PointOnPath(context: context)
  point.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude
  point.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude
  point.segment = segment
  try? context.save()
```

I thought about putting the above lines of code into:

```
var userPath: [CLLocationCoordinate2D]? {
    if let userLocations = locationManager.userLocations {  
        // Maybe add to CoreData for PointOnPath here?
        return userLocations.map( { $0.coordinate })
    }
    return nil
}
```

But I noticed this is being called many times. It seems to me it should only be called whenever a new userLocations?.append(location) happens but that's not the case and it's called many more times than userLocations?.append(location) happens. And in general I am not sure if that's the best place to save the location data in PointOnPath. Any insight is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There still is **absolutely no reason** why the view should be responsible for saving entities to the database. (or even accessing)
Neither with Storyboard nor with SwiftUI.

Depending on your architecture, you could create a ViewModel which would have access to your LocationManager and a, let's say, DataManger. This one would be responsible to save stuff to your database.

You might want to check out [this](https://medium.com/swlh/getting-started-with-swiftui-and-combine-using-mvvm-and-protocols-for-ios-d8c37731a1d9) article.