# How can I get user location with MapKit?

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-location, swiftui-map

I write map app for iOS 17 with Xcode 15. And I have problem with detecting user location.

So, I add the parameters to info

[image: info]

And I create Map() with MapUserLocationButton()

```
var body: some View {
        Map(scope: mapScope){
            UserAnnotation()
        }
        .mapControls() {
            VStack {
                MapUserLocationButton(scope: mapScope)
                MapScaleView(scope: mapScope)
            }
        }
        .mapControlVisibility(Visibility.visible)
    }
```

And if I push MapUserLocationButton I got error:
`CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x28377a500>) for <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x280773210> did fail with error: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"`

I also tried to add:

```
 let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

.onAppear {
    locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(locationManager)
}

func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:  // Location services are available.
            enableLocationFeatures()
            break
            
        case .restricted, .denied:  // Location services currently unavailable.
            disableLocationFeatures()
            break
            
        case .notDetermined:        // Authorization not determined yet.
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            break
            
        default:
            break
        }
    }
```

but it didn't get result.

What I do wrong?

---

Console screenshot:
[image: Console screenshot]

Comment: Did you add the proper entitlements and the usage key in Info.plist?

Comment: @vadian Yes. I added a picture to the quest

Comment: have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17164298/10284355

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia, I set Allow Location Simulation and Debug > Location, but it didn't fix a problem.
I can also reproduce this error on real device

Comment: Can you please attach a full screenshot of the console so I can check the error in detail?

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia I attached

Comment: i got same issue and i solved my problem with this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57690149/20693520

Comment: @mohammadgdz I tried. Same(

Comment: is it possible for you to share the code? @Aryesia

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia Sure. Here: https://github.com/Aryesia/TouristApp

Comment: @Aryesia Please do not post pictures of text. Please replace the picture of the console output with a copy and paste of the text. Pictures can't be searched or referenced and it is much harder to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add these permissions to your `.plist` file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR MESSAGE</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR MESSAGE</string>
    <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR MESSAGE</string>
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR MESSAGE</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>YOUR MESSAGE</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It is also recommended to use this `delegate` method to get exact errors.

```swift
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
}
```

[image]

Comment: You only need to add the specific location privacy keys that your app actually uses. You do not need to add all of them. Besides, the OP clearly shows they already have the needed privacy entries in the Info.plist.